# How do you copy raw Microsoft Word fields codes to another text document?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office-2007, microsoft-word-2007, copy-paste, field-codes

Is it possible to copy text from a Word document containing field codes, so that when pasted into another application, the FIELD CODES REMAIN AS RAW TEXT, i.e. something like

`This is about whales { XE "Cetations:Whales" }. This is about dolphins { XE "Cetations:Dolphins" }.`

rather than have the field codes stripped out?

Comment: Perhaps I havn't explained it very clearly. I don't want to cut and paste individual field codes one at a time, but rather the body text of entire document with the field codes kept intact...

Answer (score 1):

[TWood](https://superuser.com/users/91963/twood)'s comment is correct that with the solution from [integratorIT](https://superuser.com/users/123423/integratorit) all formatting is lost. The following macro *FieldToText* REPLACES all fields in your document with their field codes as raw text WITHOUT touching formatting.

The second macro *TextToField* is for the opposite way: raw code to fields. It looks for the pattern `{ * }` and tries to convert that to a field. It will work for the fields' raw texts inserted from the first macro, but it may give unpredicted results if there are those combinations of curly braces and whitespace somewhere else in the text where they do not indicate a (former) field function.

```
Sub FieldToText()
    'Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory            ' to start from top of document
    ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes = True
    Do
        With Selection.Find
            .Text = "^d"
            .Replacement.Text = ""
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindStop
            .Format = False
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
        End With
        Selection.Find.Execute
        If Selection.Find.Found = False Then Exit Do

        Selection = "{ " & Mid(Selection, 3, Len(Selection) - 2 - 2) & " }"
        Selection.Move wdCharacter, 1
    Loop While True
End Sub
Sub TextToField()
    Dim code As String
    'Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory            ' to start from top of document
    Do
        With Selection.Find
            .Text = "\{ * \}"
            .Replacement.Text = ""
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindStop
            .Format = False
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchWildcards = True
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
        End With
        Selection.Find.Execute
        If Selection.Find.Found = False Then Exit Do

        code = Mid(Selection, 3, Len(Selection) - 2 - 2)
        Selection.Cut
        Selection.InsertAfter (code)
        Selection.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, PreserveFormatting:=False

        Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
        Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1

    Loop While True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> to show the field code, then highlight all the text inside the curly braces `{ }`.  You can then copy and paste this text.

Here's a link to a macro someone wrote to do all the work: [Copy and Pasting Field Codes](http://word.tips.net/Pages/T003844_Copying_and_Pasting_Field_Codes.html)

Comment: In office 2010 its ALT+F9 cant check right now its the same in previous versions.

Answer (score 0):

Add macro to document, select text, run macro. You can now copy field codes to the clipboard.

Ps.: In Office 2010 <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> is used to display field codes.

```
Sub StuffFieldCode()
    Dim sField As String
    Dim sTextCode As String
    Dim bSFC As Boolean
    Dim MyData As DataObject
    Dim sTemp As String
    Dim J As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    If Selection.Fields.Count = 1 Then
        bSFC = Selection.Fields.Item(1).ShowCodes
        Selection.Fields.Item(1).ShowCodes = True
        sField = Selection.Text
        sTextCode = ""
        For J = 1 To Len(sField)
            sTemp = Mid(sField, J, 1)
            Select Case sTemp
                Case Chr(19)
                    sTemp = "{"
                Case Chr(21)
                    sTemp = "}"
                Case vbCr
                    sTemp = ""
            End Select
            sTextCode = sTextCode & sTemp
        Next J

        Set MyData = New DataObject
        MyData.SetText sTextCode
        MyData.PutInClipboard

        Selection.Fields.Item(1).ShowCodes = bSFC
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: for this code to run you have to add microsoft forms 2.0 reference to macro. It is located c:\windows\system32\FM20.dll. Unfortunately even though the code copies the text representing the field code all of the formatting is lost when it is copied. When you paste back it is simply text.

Comment: if you update, ill delete my answer

Answer (score 0):

***Sometimes I wonder about the mods... Edit was rejected - told to make new answer... This fixes a logical/typo error above.***

[TWood](https://superuser.com/users/91963/twood)'s comment is correct that with the solution from [integratorIT](https://superuser.com/users/123423/integratorit) all formatting is lost. The following macro *FieldToText* REPLACES all fields in your document with their field codes as raw text WITHOUT touching formatting.

The second macro *TextToField* is for the opposite way: raw code to fields. It looks for the pattern `{*}` and tries to convert that to a field. It will work for the fields' raw texts inserted from the first macro, but it may give unpredicted results if there are those combinations of curly braces and whitespace somewhere else in the text where they do not indicate a (former) field function.

```
Sub FieldToText()
    'Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory            ' to start from top of document
    ActiveWindow.View.ShowFieldCodes = True
    Do
        With Selection.Find
            .Text = "^d"
            .Replacement.Text = ""
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindStop
            .Format = False
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
        End With
        Selection.Find.Execute
        If Selection.Find.Found = False Then Exit Do
        
        Selection = "{ " & Mid(Selection, 3, Len(Selection) - 2 - 2) & " }"
        Selection.Move wdCharacter, 1
    Loop While True
End Sub
Sub TextToField()
    Dim code As String
    'Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory            ' to start from top of document
    Do
        With Selection.Find
            .Text = "\{*\}"
            .Replacement.Text = ""
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindStop
            .Format = False
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = False
            .MatchWildcards = True
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
        End With
        Selection.Find.Execute
        If Selection.Find.Found = False Then Exit Do
        
        code = Selection 
        code = Left(code, Len(code) - 1)
        code = Right(code, Len(code) - 1)
        code = Trim(code)
        Selection.Cut
        Selection.InsertAfter (code)
        Selection.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldEmpty, PreserveFormatting:=False
        
        Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
        Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdWord, Count:=1
    
    Loop While True
End Sub
```

Comment: So now we have 2 almost identical answers. The reason for rejection might be that you're trying to correct a 4 year old answer by an active member of the community. Is there a specific reason for not simply dropping a comment for @Traveler about the perceived error in his answer, as is customary? I would do that instead, and delete this answer.

Comment: I did an edit - it was rejected with "you should provide an answer"
A comment is not suitable for copy/paste of a solution, and the previous answer (which I tried to edit) has subtle issues.